# Partial Least Squares for validating a Framework

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, partial-least-squares

I understand that PLS can indicate the cronbach's alpha between two variables in a Framework.

(i) For instance, can PLS tell us, based on the direction of the arrows, if there is causation (i.e. one var influence the other)?

(ii) Will PLS tell us if one var is influencing another var in the Framework?

(iii) What additional info can we glean using PLS?

(iv) How do we determine if there is a latent var in a Framework?